# fix double payments - double purchases

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

i'm implementing an online payment platform similar to paypal, **the problem is that when they click on the buy button 2 times or more quickly and this causes the payment to register twice instead of once**

**When you click buy execute this action:**

```
     public function invoke(Request $request) {
    
      $payment_id = $request->get('payment_id');
    
      $credenciales = config('services.mercadopago.token');
      $request->get('user_id'));
    
      $response = Http::get("https://api.mercadopago.com/v1/payments/$payment_id" . "?access_token=$credenciales");
      
      $response = json_decode($response);

  $request->session()->put('order', $response->order->id);
  $request->session()->put('ingreso', $response->transaction_details->net_received_amount);
  $request->session()->put('monto', $response->transaction_details->total_paid_amount);
  $request->session()->put('method', $response->payment_type_id); 
 $status = $response->status;
```

**If the answer is approved run this:**

```
if($status == 'approved') {


  Income::insert([
    'user_id'       => Session::get('user_id'),
    'evento_id'       => Session::get('variableName'),
    //Guardar el personal seleccionado
    'mp_id'  => Session::get('order'),
    'metodo'        => Session::get('metodo'),
    'monto'        => Session::get('monto'),
    'rrpp_id'         => Session::get('rrpp'),
    'ingreso'        => Session::get('ingreso'),


  ]);

  OrderNew::insert([
    'user_id'       => Session::get('user_id'),
    'dia_id'       => Session::get('variableName'),
    //Guardar el personal seleccionado
    'whatsapp'  => Session::get('telefono'),
    'cantidad'        => Session::get('cantidad'),
    'anticipada'        => Session::get('anticipada'),
    'horario'        => Session::get('horario'),
    'rrpp'         => Session::get('rrpp'),
    'pagado'        => '1',
    'tipo'        => 'vip',
    'codigo'        => rand(1580, 4005),


  ]);
```

in the first model I register the incoming money and in the second model I register the customer's order

and there is the problem, if they click on Buy several times, the records are duplicated and they get free products

**How can I limit or solve this problem?**

Comment: The easy solution is to disable the submit button once clicked, hard solution involves more work...

Comment: Instead of Insert use `updateOrCreate` or maybe `firstOrCreate` which accepts 2 parameters, first one an array to check the values against and second to insert data. If the records match, it will be updated, otherwise a new one will be inserted. Please check Laravel docs for `updateOrCreate`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Insert use `updateOrCreate` or maybe `firstOrCreate` that accepts 2 parameters, first one an array to check the values against database records and second to insert/find data. If the records match, it will be updated/retrieved, otherwise a new one will be created. Please check Laravel docs for `updateOrCreate` or `firstOrCreate`.

In your case, for example:

```
Income::firstOrCreate([
    'user_id'       => Session::get('user_id'),
    'evento_id'       => Session::get('variableName'),
    //Guardar el personal seleccionado
    'mp_id'  => Session::get('order'),
    'metodo'        => Session::get('metodo'),
    'monto'        => Session::get('monto'),
    'rrpp_id'         => Session::get('rrpp'),
    'ingreso'        => Session::get('ingreso'),
  ]);
```

This will check the exact records and if it finds a match it retrieves the data, otherwise creates one which avoids duplicated entries.

However, since your second query has a random number generated, it will not find a match if we pass only one argument, therefore, as a first argument we need to pass the array to be checked against the database (all data, except for the `rand()` part).

```
OrderNew::firstOrCreate(
  [
    'user_id'       => Session::get('user_id'),
    'dia_id'       => Session::get('variableName'),
    //Guardar el personal seleccionado
    'whatsapp'  => Session::get('telefono'),
    'cantidad'        => Session::get('cantidad'),
    'anticipada'        => Session::get('anticipada'),
    'horario'        => Session::get('horario'),
    'rrpp'         => Session::get('rrpp'),
    'pagado'        => '1',
    'tipo'        => 'vip',
  ],
  [
    'user_id'       => Session::get('user_id'),
    'dia_id'       => Session::get('variableName'),
    //Guardar el personal seleccionado
    'whatsapp'  => Session::get('telefono'),
    'cantidad'        => Session::get('cantidad'),
    'anticipada'        => Session::get('anticipada'),
    'horario'        => Session::get('horario'),
    'rrpp'         => Session::get('rrpp'),
    'pagado'        => '1',
    'tipo'        => 'vip',
    'codigo'        => rand(1580, 4005),
  ]);
```

According to your data, you can change the array of data to be checked against the database.

Answer (score 0):

Specify that the route should not allow concurrent requests from the same session.

```
Route::get('/deposit',ExampleController::class)->block(10);
```

Comment: Interesting; I had no idea this existed. https://laravel.com/api/10.x/Illuminate/Routing/Route.html#method_block